# Enable Twig debug doesn't work?

Tags: theming, 8, debugging

Why isn't the Twig debug working on my Drupal 8.2.6 site?

This is the folder structure.

[image: File structure]

These are the folder permissions.

[image: Folder permissions]

This is the content of the settings.php file.

```
$settings['hash_salt'] = 'DEVELOPMENT_SALT';
$settings['update_free_access'] = FALSE;
$settings['file_public_base_url'] = 'http://localhost/files';
$settings['file_public_path'] = 'sites/default/files';
$settings['file_private_path'] = 'sites/default/private';
$settings['file_scan_ignore_directories'] = [
  'node_modules',
  'bower_components',
];
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../development/settings.development.php'))     {
  include __DIR__ . '/../development/settings.development.php';
}
```

Here I include /../development/settings.development.php.

```
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, TRUE);
\Drupal\Component\Assertion\Handle::register();

/**
 * Enable local development services.
 */
$settings['container_yamls'][] = __DIR__ . '/development.services.yml';

$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'dbname',
  'username' => 'dbusername',
  'password' => 'pw',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);

$settings['hash_salt'] = 'DEVELOPMENT';

$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] =     'cache.backend.null';
$settings['extension_discovery_scan_tests'] = TRUE;
$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;
$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = TRUE;
```

Here I also add development.services.yml.

```
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Things I have checked/done:

- Checked if all these files are loaded -> They are
- Checked the indentation of the development.services.yml -> Checks out
- Cleared all the different caches, rebuild them, etc -> If I change a template, it changes, but no Twig debugging

sites/default/files AND sites/default/private are not used by Drupal.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change your `development.services.yml` to following. this  works for me correctly(I hope works for you too) .

```
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory

# Enable Twig debugging.
parameters:
 twig.config:
   debug: true
   auto_reload: true
   cache: false
```

also  this [article about setting up debugging on Drupal 8](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/drupal-8-theming-setting-up-theme-debugging) is very good for future visitors of this question.

Comment: Thanks! This is the formatting that finally worked for me.

Comment: @RobbDavis you're welcome, good to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Services should come before parameters ...also... If you don't want to enable all the 'stuff' you have in settings.local.php you can just add... 
`$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';`
to the bottom of your settings.php file to turn on twig debug after adding the parameters to development.services.yml.

I use both this and...

```
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
   include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
```

Commenting out one or the other depending on what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems everything is correct and I guess you just forget check "Show comments" on your browser.

[image]

Comment: This is not the case, because I am using Chrome's inspector.

Comment: @user3634184 try to check it on firefox ,just for test.